# Generate random words

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

apple, mango, papaya, banana, guava, pineapple - How to generate these words randomly (one by one) using c# ? Please help me to generate the words randomly from the list of words I have..

Answer (score 5):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string GetRandomFruit()
{
    string[] fruits = new string[] { "apple", "mango", "papaya", "banana", "guava", "pineapple" };
    return fruits[rnd.Next(0,fruits.Length)];
}
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that Sasi wanted a permutation algorithm, rather than a random selection with replacement?

Comment: @Phillip IMO could be interpreted either way - OP isn't clear.

Answer (score 4):

You can get "random sorting" with LINQ's `OrderBy` method and using `Guid`s

```
var words = new [] {"apple", "mango", "papaya", "banana", "guava", "pineapple"};
var wordsInRandomOrder = words.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid());

foreach(var word in wordsInRandomOrder)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

The following `foreach` will give you **each item once** from the `words` array in a random order.

Comment: I like your solution! Except Sasi indicated C#-2 in the tags.

Answer (score 3):

you can write the following code.

```
string[] fruits = new string[] { "apple", "mango", "papaya", "banana", "guava", "pineapple" };
Console.WriteLine(fruits[new Random().Next(0, fruits.Length)]);
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Creating a new `Random()` could seed with the same seed and result in the same output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Fisher-Yates to do an in place shuffle of an array:

```
static class ArrayMethods
{
    private static readonly Random rng = new Random();
    public static void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> list)
    {
      var r = rng;
      var len = list.Count;
      for(var i = len-1; i >= 1; --i)
      {
          var j = r.Next(i);
          var tmp = list[i];
          list[i] = list[j];
          list[j] = tmp;
      }

    }
}
```

as follows:

```
var arr = new[]{
  "apple", 
  "mango", 
  "papaya", 
  "banana", 
  "guava", 
  "pineapple"
};
ArrayMethods.Shuffle(arr);
foreach(var item in arr)
    //print 'em out
```